# what is operator class_name() const?

Tags: c++

From  Item 15, I noticed these code:

```
class FontHandle { ... };

class Font {
public:
  // implicit conversion function
  operator FontHandle() const { return f; }
private:
  FontHandle f;
};
```

It *seems like* that class `Font` overloaded other class's constructor, is it? We commonly see the `+-*/=` overload definition, bu why this happen? Which are the situations should we do like that?

Comment: There is a comment explaining that it's an implicit conversion, are you interested in what the const does? Or you are not the author of the comment?

Comment: It's a conversion operator. See [this explanation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr383.htm).

Comment: Ok, I really know it's a implicite conversion. But...I have dropped C++ for years and now just want to pick back something. I even do not know why there need such a conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a user-defined conversion operator.

It allows an *implicit* conversion from `Font` to `FontHandle`.  That is, it allows code like this:

```
Font f;
// ...
FontHandle fh = f;  // Conversion applied here
```

Without such an operator, the line above would yield a compiler error along the lines of "no conversion possible between unrelated types"

Answer (score 3):

```
operator FontHandle() const { return f; }
```

This is a conversion operator. It will allow you to use a `Font` object where a `FontHandle` is called for. The implementation in this case just returns a copy of the private `FontHandle` `f`.

The `const` in this example tells the compiler that this will not modify the `Font` object, and thus can be used with `const` `Font` objects.

Answer (score 0):

`const` appearing after function name marks the "this" pointer constant, that is, the method is not allowed to alter the invariant of the object. A "side effect" of this is that you can call this method on const objects, as there is a guarantee that it "won't fiddle with the data members".

(As stated in your comments, that call is an implicit conversion.)

Comment: I wanted to say preceding function definition, not declaration, brainfart, thanks for the fix.